# Location update fires avery 2 seconds

Tags: android, location

I have the following code which is a Service that finds the device's current location and sends it to a webservice.

The service is started from a push notification (firebase). The firebase class that receives the push then starts an IntentService that in turn call this plain Android service with the location in.

I have to use an IntentService to fire off the service as my application also handles another 500 different pushes to execute various functionality which may include web calls.

The problem i am having is on certain devices eg samsung galaxy s6, once the location service starts, it repeatedly gets a new lock every 2 seconds.... forever. (even though i call stopself on the service). On my S7, it gets a lock once and all is well. The s6 is android 6 and the s7 is Android 7.

I have noticed i call the following line to start looking for updates, passing in 0,0 for the time and distance intervals. Should i set them to a higher value?

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener, looper);
```

If this is not the problem, i understand i should be using Google Play Services Location APIs.

[Google Play Services Location APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

but i cannot find any tutorials that show me how to use these apis inside a service to only find the location once.

Has anyone any ideas why location updates are firing every 2 seconds only on certain phones?

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    LocationListener mlocListener;
    AppObj appObj;


    Handler endServiceHandler;
    Runnable endServiceRunnable;
    HandlerThread handlerThread;
    Looper looper;
    Location mLoc;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "inside tracking service onStartCommand");

        appObj = (AppObj) getApplication();
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Log.e(TAG, "Service created and location manager and listener created");

        Log.e(TAG, "creating handlerthread and looper");
        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
        handlerThread.start();
        looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener, looper);
        Log.e(TAG, "requesting location updates");   
        killLocationRequestHandler();
        endServiceHandler.postDelayed(endServiceRunnable, 45 * 1000);  
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "in onDestroy in LocationService class");
        try {
            mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
        }catch(Exception e){}   
    }

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }    
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            mLoc = loc;    
            Log.e(TAG, "in TrackingService onlocationChanged and about to send lat/lon " +  loc.getLatitude() + " " + loc.getLongitude());   

            DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
            DateTimeFormatter df3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").withLocale(Locale.UK).withOffsetParsed();
            String formattedNowTime3 = df3.print(dt);
            Log.e(TAG, "Time of location fix in TrackingService = " + formattedNowTime3);
            appObj.webService.sendUserLocation(formattedNowTime3, String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "co-ods = " + String.valueOf(mLoc.getLatitude())
                            + " " + String.valueOf(mLoc.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });    
            Log.e(TAG, "quiting handlerthread");
            handlerThread.quit();

            try {
                mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
            }catch(Exception e){}
            Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService)");        
            TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
            Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService");

        }    
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {    

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


        }

    }      
    public void killLocationRequestHandler() {

        endServiceHandler = new Handler();
        endServiceRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {  
                endService();    
            }

            private void endService() {

                try {
                    mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
                }catch(Exception e){}
                Log.e(TAG, "removed updates(TrackingService) from the endService handler");

                DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                DateTimeFormatter df3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS");
                String formattedNowTime3 = df3.print(dt);
                Log.e(TAG, "Time of location fix in TrackingService = " + formattedNowTime3);

                appObj.webService.sendUserLocation(formattedNowTime3, "NO_LAT", "NO_LON");


                TrackingService.this.stopSelf();
                Log.e(TAG, "called stopSelf on TrackingService from the endService handler");

            }
        };

    }


}// end of service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one update, use requestSingleUpdate.  Its meant to only fire once.